# Trouble using DatePicker in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I have implemented a `DatePicker` dialog using the following code:

```
static final int DATE_PICKER_FROM = 0;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener from_dateListener;
private EditText editDateStart;
...
private void addListenersToButtons(){
    editDateStart = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDateStart);

    editDateStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_FROM);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_PICKER_FROM:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, from_dateListener,2,10,2013);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The following is the inizialization of the listener:

```
 from_dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                    int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                    int year = selectedYear;
                    int month = selectedMonth;
                    int day = selectedDay;

            editDateStart.setText(
                    new StringBuilder()
                        .append(pad(day)).append("/")
                        .append(pad(month + 1)).append("/")
                        .append(year).append(" "));
            }
        };
```

When the EditText field is clicked the Dialog showed is the following:

[image]

So, the  date I tried to set using the code:

```
DatePickerDialog(this, from_dateListener,2,10,2013);
```

does not appears. As you can see the date is 1 gen 1900.

Another problem occurs when I try to change the day in the datepicker. For example I have setted from 1 to 2 and the result is the following:

[image]

The calendar has reached the date 2 feb 2036. Why?

NOTE: If I change the year in the datepicker from 1900 to 1901 the calendar year change to 2037, but If I set the date to 1902 in the datepicker, the year in calendar become 1902 (and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation of [`DatePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog%28android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) constructor. The parameters are as follows:

> public **DatePickerDialog** (Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *context*  The context the dialog is to run in.
>
> *callBack* How the parent is notified that the date is set.
>
> *year* The initial year of the dialog.
>
> *monthOfYear*  The initial month of the dialog.
>
> *dayOfMonth*   The initial day of the dialog.

So the call should be:

```
DatePickerDialog(this, from_dateListener, 2013, 10, 2);
```

Comment: You are right @Rajesh. Now it is working. Just another question: If I open dialog and I change the date without pressing IMPOSTA button, just pressing ANNULLA the dialog is closed, but when I reopen it the date I had previously setted remains. How can I set the date to 2/11/2013 each time I reopen the dialog?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`updateDate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#updateDate(int,%20int,%20int)) method?

Answer (score 1):

Do some thing like this

```
DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, datePickerListener, Year, Month, Day);
```